Virt-Manager created qemu VMs (Nat to eth0) break host internet via routes to vm
With all the VMs i created in Virt-Manager using QEMU Backend i use the "default" network interface of NATing to the Ethernet Device.
When starting any VM, the Network Connection drops and Browsers have spurious errors redirecting to where you already are.
Checking ip route show the problem is obvious:
0.0.0.0 dev vnet0 scope link
default dev vnet0 scope link

top the list, thus sinking all traffic into the VM.
Deleting the routes restores connectivity (as does shutting down the VM)
How can i change either virt-man or my system so that these routes are not always used?
Since the vnet device changes every reboot of the vm, i think fixing it in virt-man is necessary to have a reliable fix?
This is the networks xml config:
<network connections="1">
  <name>network</name>
  <uuid>uuid</uuid>
  <forward dev="eth0" mode="nat">
    <nat>
      <port start="1024" end="65535"/>
    </nat>
    <interface dev="eth0"/>
  </forward>
  <bridge name="virbr1" stp="on" delay="0"/>
  <mac address="[[MAC]]"/>
  <domain name="network"/>
  <ip address="192.168.100.1" netmask="255.255.255.0">
    <dhcp>
      <range start="192.168.100.128" end="192.168.100.254"/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>

